# Octopus deploy in azure blue and green environments

Tags: azure, powershell, octopus-deploy

I am trying to deploy an app service in azure using octopus for blue and green environments.
It all work apart of the step that tries to swap.
Here are my steps,
Step 1

```
New-AzureRmWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName quantum-apps-dev -Name QuantumDev -Slot green
```

Step 2

```
Deploy app service
```

Step 3

```
Switch-AzureWebsiteSlot –Name QuantumDev -Slot1 "green" -Force
```

Step 4

```
Remove-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName quantum-apps-dev -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/slots –Name QuantumDev/green -Force
```

However step 3 is failing with the following error,

Calamari.exe : CloseError: No default subscription has been designated. Use Select-AzureSubscription -Default  to set the default subscription.

I have added the suggested command above but still failing and complaining that cannot find the subscription

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Try ```Switch-AzureRmWebsiteSlot``` instead of ```Switch-AzureWebsiteSlot```. They're both valid cmdlets, but from different PowerShell modules. Since you're using ```New-AzureRmWebAppSlot``` successfully, the AzureRm version of ```Switch-AzureRmWebsiteSlot``` is likely to work as well, although it has slightly different parameters. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/switch-azurermwebappslot?view=azurermps-6.13.0 vs https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicemanagement/azure.service/switch-azurewebsiteslot?view=azuresmps-4.0.0 for details.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked like a dream

Comment: I have summarize the comment into reply to help others who have same problem. You can accept it as answer to close this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`Switch-AzureRmWebsiteSlot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/switch-azurermwebappslot?view=azurermps-6.13.0) instead of [`Switch-AzureWebsiteSlot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicemanagement/azure.service/switch-azurewebsiteslot?view=azuresmps-4.0.0).

Both of them are used to swap the production slot for a website with another slot.
As you are using `New-AzureRmWebAppSlot` successfully, the AzureRM module means work well.

So try to `use Switch-AzureRmWebsiteSlot`.